# Conditional featured image with youtube thumbnail

Tags: php, custom-field, conditional-content

Basically what I am trying to do here is: Display the youtube thumbnail. If no youtube thumbnail -> Display the Featured image for the post. If no featured image -> Display the fallback image.

However it seems I am doing something wrong because the webpage displays blank.

```
<?php
            // Check if the post has a Youtube thumbnail (using custom field video_url)
    if get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)
        echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true) . '/0.jpg"/>';
            // Check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it
    else ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" >';
        the_post_thumbnail('frontpage-thumb');
        echo '</a>';
            // If the post does not have a featured image then display the fallback image
    } else {
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($post->ID) . '" ><img src="'. get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/img/fallback-featured-image-index.jpg" /></a>';}
    ?>
```

The general code for displaying the youtube thumbnail with custom fields is `<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true);?>/0.jpg"/>` I just can't get it to work with the conditional statements...

Comment: You have php tags inside your first `echo` statement. Should be `echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' .  get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true) .'/0.jpg"/>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three problems

### 1. echo and php tags within an echo

Change your first echo from:

```
 echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true);?>/0.jpg"/>';
```

to this:

```
 echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true) . '/0.jpg"/>';
```

### 2. if statement not wrapped and no brackets

change:

```
 if get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)
```

to:

```
 if (get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true))
```

and add `{}` around that code block:

```
if (get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true)) {
    echo '<img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/' . get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url',true) . '/0.jpg"/>';
        // Check if the post has a Post Thumbnail assigned to it
}
```

### 3. else instead of elseif

the first else should be an `elseif`. so change:

```
else ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
```

to:

```
elseif ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
```

Hope that is all of them. In the future try using a tool such as [PHP Code Checker](http://phpcodechecker.com/) to check your code.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the code but the webpage is displaying blank. Must be something else that is not working...

Comment: Turn wp debug on to track down the problem.

Comment: I am not able to use wp debug. It is a live site.

Comment: If you can't turn debug in then I wouldn't suggest testing code on it ether.

Comment: Can you give a [Paste Bin](http://pastebin.com/), or something like that, with the whole template code?

Comment: https://codeshare.io/7oknj

Comment: I found the problems. I updated my answer to address them. Hope that is all of them :)